# Code compiles with netcore but will not compile using mono

Tags: compiler-errors, f#, .net-core, mono

I'm running `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS`, using mono version `5.18.0.2140`, and my code won't compile under mono while it does compile if I use `netcore` with VS Code. However, I'm required to use mono for this assignment, so I'm not sure what's going wrong. The command I'm using is:

```sh
fsharpc --nologo chessApp.fsx && mono chessApp.exe
```

The error happens in this part of the code ([from this line and down](https://gist.github.com/Dumbledorf/0d86c8e43b83f824b2a673c59ca761f2#file-chessapp-fsx-L28), full gist at the bottom):

```
let playerOne = Chess.Human(Color.White) // Here
let playerTwo = Chess.Human(Color.Black) // Here

let game = new Chess.Game()
game.run(playerOne, playerTwo, board, pieces) // and here
```

The error I'm getting is the following:

```
 chessApp.fsx(28,17): The object constructor 'Human' takes 0 argument(s) but is here given 1. The requried signature is 'new : unit -> Human'.

 chessApp.fsx(29,17): The object constructor 'Human' takes 0 argument(s) but is here given 1. The requried signature is 'new : unit -> Human'.

 chessApp.fsx(31,1): This value is not a function and cannot be applied.
```

I don't get these errors using VS Code. It works there. For example, `Human` does take 1 argument netcore on VS Code recognizes that but mono does not. In order to not make this question longer than it has to be, I've uploaded the code to a gist [right here](https://gist.github.com/Dumbledorf/0d86c8e43b83f824b2a673c59ca761f2).

Answer (score 2):

I tried reproducing this by running the compiler from command line on Windows. There are two minor errors in your `fsx` source file. First, you are opening a wrong namespace:

```
#r "chess.dll"
#r "pieces.dll"

open Chess
open Pieces // <- This should be open 'Piece'
```

Second, the `pieces` collection needs to be a list, not an array:

```
let pieces =
   [ king (White) :> chessPiece
     rook (White) :> chessPiece
     king (Black) :> chessPiece
     rook (Black) :> chessPiece ]
```

With these two changes, I was able to compile everything:

```
fsharpc --target:library chess.fs
fsharpc --target:library -r:chess.dll pieces.fs
fsharpc chessApp.fsx
```

Note that you need `--target:library` to indicate that this should  build a `dll` file and also `-r:chess.dll` for the second file to tell it that it needs to reference the first `dll`.

It would be a lot easier if you referenced the two other files as source files using `#load` rather than as compiled files using `#r`:

```
#load "chess.fs"
#load "pieces.fs"
```

Then you can compile the whole thing just by running `fsharpc chessApp.fsx` and you'll get a single stand-alone executable.

Comment: Oh shoot, I totally looked over that. Thank you very much!